# Insert data into existing child firebase

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

First of all, I want to apologize for my poor English.

The last week I started to explore AngularJS in the Ionic framework with Firebase as backend. But I’ve stumbled upon a problem that I can’t solve for the past 3 days.

The purpose is when I chose a storage place and confirm it, an inventory will be created with a date and a link to the storage place to know to which storage place the inventory belongs. After that a list of products will be shown. When you chose a product, a new screen appears where you can add the amount of that product.

My problem is, I can create an inventory after confirmation, but it seems like I can’t insert the product with the amount inside the just created inventory.

Before insertion:

```
- Inventories
  - Date: 1449767729166
  - storage: "My Storage place 1"
```

I want my database looks like this after the insert:

```
- Inventories
  - Date: 1449767729166
  - storage: "My Storage place 1"
  - Products: 
     - Name: Heineken
     - Boxes: 12
     - Bottles: 6
```

Here is my code:

addProducts.html

```
<div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label"><p>Aantal volle bakken/boxes</p></span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Aantal volle bakken/boxes" ng-model="products.boxes">
      </label>
      <br>
      <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label"><p>Aantal (losse) flessen</p></span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Aantal (losse) flessen" ng-model="products.flessen">
      </label>
      <br>
      <button class="button button-block button-dark" align="left" ng-click="AddProducts(products)">
        Toevoegen
      </button>
    </div>
```

controllers.js:

```
.controller('AddProductCtrl', function($scope, $state, Inventory, Product) {

$scope.products = Inventory;
$scope.products = Product;



var now = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

$scope.AddProducts = function(products) {
  var query = Product.orderByChild(products.storage).equalTo('now');
  query.once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref().child('Products').push({
        'Boxes' : fullBox,
        'Bottles': losFles
    });
});
```

}})

services.js

```
.factory('Product', ['$firebaseArray', function($firebaseArray) {
   var addProductRef = new Firebase('https://testdb-1.firebaseio.co/Inventories/');

  return $firebaseArray(addProductRef); }])
```

My Firebase structure:
[Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPwXt.png)

This is the error I got:

> Error: Product.orderByChild is not a function

I already tried serveral things but with no success.
I'm really new to this. So, please point out what I did wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Product` factory returns a [`$firebaseArray`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray), which does not have an [`orderByChild()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/orderbychild.html) method.

I can't really figure out your use-case, but one way to solve the error message:

```
.factory('Product', ['$firebaseArray', function($firebaseArray) {
   var addProductRef = new Firebase('https://testdb-1.firebaseio.co/Inventories/');

  return addProductRef; 
}])
```

So instead of returning a `$firebaseArray` this returns a `Firebase` reference, which *has* the `orderByChild` method you're looking to use.

And then:

```
$scope.AddProducts = function(products) {
  var query = Product.orderByChild(products.storage).equalTo('now');
  query.once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref().child('Products').push({
        'Boxes' : fullBox,
        'Bottles': losFles
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this. But it still got the same error.

I’ve now modified my controller.js and  as you said I removed $firebaseArray in my services.js . Now the controller looks like this:

    Product.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
          snapshot.ref().child("Products").update({
          'Boxes' : fullBox,
          'Bottles' : losFles
        });

      });

Now it does insert into the child node, but it inserted it into the whole Inventories node. That’s not what I want. I want to add it to a specific child. The child the user just created. But I don’t know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the confusion comes from mixing up the Firebase SDK with the AngularFire API.

You properly create `Products` factory using a `$firebaseArray()`, but then you try to use it like a regular Firebase reference.

A `$firebaseArray()` takes in a Firebase references and wraps all of the child events (`child_added`, `child_changed`, etc...) and create a synchronized array.

You can try using a factory to get the products:

```
.constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
.service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
.factory('productsByDate', function(rootRef, $q) {
  return function productsByDate(storage) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var productRef = rootRef.child('products'); // or however you get there
    var localNow = new Date().getTime();
    var query = Product.orderByChild(storage).equalTo(localNow);
    query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
      deferred.resolve(snapshot);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };
});
```

Try this in your controller:

```
.controller('AddProductCtrl', function($scope, $state, Inventory, Product, productsByDate) {

$scope.products = Inventory;
$scope.products = Product;

var now = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

$scope.AddProducts = function(products) {
    // get your products by date
    productsByDate(products.storage).then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.ref().child('Products').push({
        'Boxes' : fullBox,
        'Bottles': losFles
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I’v tried this, but then I got an error saying that productsByDate is not a function. I’ve already checked a few times to make sure that I didn’t forgot to add productsByDate in my controller.